# Typo3 Backend Login auth service with multiple steps

Tags: authentication, typo3

I am trying to implement a 2factor login for the typo3 **backend** to authenticate via a mobile App / Api. 
I tried an auth service with getUser and authUser overrides and my own login template in ext_tables.php which works great with just the login form. 
However, I need multiple views / steps:

1. Form with App-UserID & submit button
2. Accesspass & submit button

I tried to display the 2. view with

```
GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');
```

In the authUser function but I am looking for a cleaner (maybe MVC/extbase?) approach or best practice.
How can I implement a 2 step backend login and pass variables between those views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is not possible. TYPO3 checks all installed Auth-Services in the order of the priority of each service. There is no point, where you can hook into that process and stop the authentication process to display a form.

I would suggest to implement the accesspass field into your custom TYPO3 backend login template, so you have 3 fields for the loginprocess. You can split the evaluation of the fields in different auth services (ordered by the priority of your need). For a working example see my [YubiKey TYPO3 extension](https://github.com/derhansen/sf_yubikey), which first authenticates the TYPO3 backend user by username/password (TYPO3 default authentication) and then by a YubiKey OTP.